How to round the result of an AVG in cosmosDB?
How to round the result of an aggregate operation (SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN) in CosmosDB?
After many tries I'm afraid to believe CosmosDb SQL API doesn't allow such types of queries or equivalent
How can I round for instance an avg of a random attribute?
pseudo query (doesn't work in cosmosDB):
SELECT ROUND(AVG(c.weight)) 
FROM c

The error
Failed to query item for container ContainerName:
 {"code":"BadRequest","message":"One of the input values is invalid.\r\nActivityId: a672d255-02f3-4f6d-bb8a-943ea70b803f, Windows/10.0.20348 cosmos-netstandard-sdk/3.18.0"}


Do you use SDK to work with Cosmos or do you just want a plain query? What "doesn't work" mean? Any errors?

ROUND and AVG in CosmosDb. Your query looks correct SELECT ROUND(AVG(c.weight)) AS roundedAverageWeight FROM c. Show us the error or details of why this doesn't work

Hello Roman Just plain SQL API Query

@RomanMarusyk - the query is not correct, as ROUND() cannot be applied to an aggregate like AVG(), as I pointed out in my answer.

Yep I got that part that is not possible to use Round, but is there a way to do it? that's the question

The following looks like it works SELECT ROUND(t.AvgWeight) FROM  ( SELECT AVG(c.weight) as AvgWeight FROM c ) t but I can't find derived tables documented so I'm not sure if this is actually supported

I'm assuming you're getting an error regarding compositions of aggregates (though you didn't provide the exact error):

"Compositions of aggregates and other expressions are not allowed."

You cannot perform something like ROUND() on an aggregate function - ROUND() is applicable directly to a property (such as ROUND(c.weight) in your case).
You'll need to round the non-rounded result (AVG(c.weight)) from Cosmos DB, in your code, as you would round any other number, using the math library function in whatever language you're using.

Hi there, I've updated the description with the error. I know it's not possible to use Round like that, but when using the SQL Query API is any there form of rounding or performing any other operations on a aggregate value? I'm afraid the answer is "no" and we have to always resort to some mix solution between SQL and code to fulfil such requirements

As I explained, you'll need to round the result you get. You could also do this in a stored procedure but that's more code than just rounding a result in your app (plus it's scoped to a single partition).

well thanks, it's a very very very very limited SQL API to be honest, but yeah thanks
